# multiple where condition in result query

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get data with multiple where condition but i do not where is problem .this query sending blank out put.any help.

```
 $user1 = $wpdb->get_results("select product,checked_by,submit_date,unit_data,temperature_in,temperature_out,time_in, time_out,category from diary_user_form_storage  where category_name='opening OR closing'  order by submit_date");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax for where is wrong it should be

```
$user1 = $wpdb->get_results("select product,checked_by,submit_date,unit_data,temperature_in,temperature_out,time_in, time_out,category from diary_user_form_storage  where category_name='opening' OR category_name='closing'  order by submit_date");
```

Comment: Sneha Agarwal@great, I just want  perform  AND operator replace of or . this answer  is good thanks , can you change or with and

Comment: Yes just have to replace OR with AND or you could also use the IN operator  where category_name IN('opening','closing')

Comment: Sneha Agarwal@well thanks  but when I used And  instead of OR then its showing  blank data, but right now i am working

Comment: Are you you have data that satisfies the AND condition